# What are the major differences between the NKJV and the ESV translations?

Tags: bible-translation, esv, nkjv

I have read both the [New King James version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_King_James_Version) and the [English Standard version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Standard_Version). I have noticed very trivial differences between the two. What, if any, are the major differences between the NKJV and the ESV?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The New King James version is meant to be an update (circa 1975) of the vocabulary and grammar of the King James Version, while preserving the classic style and literary beauty of the original 1611 KJV version. 130 translators used the original King James version as well as Greek, Aramaic, and Hebrew texts including the Dead Sea Scrolls.  The translators have sought to follow the principles of translation used in the original King James Version, which the NKJV revisers call "complete equivalence" in contrast to "dynamic equivalence" used by many other modern translations. The task of updating the English of the KJV involved significant changes in word order, grammar, vocabulary, and spelling. One of the most significant features of the NKJV was its abandonment of the historic second person pronouns “thou”, "thee", “ye”, “thy”, and “thine”. Verb forms were also modernized in the NKJV (for example, "speaks" rather than "speaketh").

The English Standard Version (ESV) of 2001 is a revision of the of the 1971 Revised Standard Version, which traces it's origins to William Tyndale's New Testament translation of 1525 (the first English translation of a Bible from the original Greek and Hebrew manuscripts, which was also a significant influence on the original KJV).  Work on the ESV began over the perceived looseness of style and content of recently published English Bible translations. Many alterations designed to correct or improve the text were made to satisfy the objections of conservative Protestants who had considered the RSV to be theologically liberal, for example, changing the translation of the Hebrew almah from "young woman" (used in the RSV) to "virgin" (in the ESV) in Isaiah 7:14. The language was modernized to remove "thou" and "thee" and replace obsolete words (e.g., "jug" for "cruse").

**Relative Differences:** the biggest practical difference that I can see is that the ESV is newer. The RSV, upon which the ESV is based, was primarily a project to update the Bible to the English language of the current time (mid-20th century) as an improvement over the old KJV.  By the time the ESV was published the New King James Version -- which also had as its goal to modernize the language -- had been published twenty years earlier.  It seems to me (a Catholic who primarily uses the Challoner revision to the Douay-Rheims and the Latin Vulgate) that the both the ESV and NKJV are projects which in their history are based on the same work (Tyndale's Bible) with the same general goals (modernized language) and which have both achieved this goal with negligible qualitative differences.

Answer (score 8):

One of the main differences between the ESV and NKJV is the underlying Greek texts.  The ESV uses whas has been called the Critical Text whereas the NKJV uses what has been called the Received Text.  The differences between these underlying greek texts is not insignificant.  A discussion of the differences between them is likely not appropriate for this venue.  My personal preference is for the Majority Text which is very similar to the Received Text in almost every way as the vast majority of greek manuscripts fall into this family.

Comment: Note that the TR or "Received Text" is also a critical text. Erasmus selected the most reliable reading from the MSS he had at his disposal. The ESV simply uses a critical text that has more MSS to consult.

Comment: I suppose that when you say this you mean that any text can be a "critical text" but that is not what I mean.  In scholarly circles the Critical Text has specific meaning, a text based primarially on the Alexandrian family of documents with some influence from the Western family, completely ignoring the Byzantine family of texts which comprise 90%+ of the available biblical texts.  The fact that they ignore the largest and most consistent family of texts, and instead chose to take texts that are much less consistent and then decide for themselves what is God's word worries me.

Comment: I run in scholarly circles. Every critical text of which I am aware takes into account the majority text. The will generally weight results from Alexandrian sources more heavily due to the age, but they certainly don't ignore the Byzantine readings.

Comment: Can you give me a specific example where a Byzantine MT reading overshadows a Alexandrian or Western reading in the CT?  I agree that, if they agree it is considered to add weight, but they never follow the Byzantine away from the other families that I know of.

Comment: The Nestle-Aland just released their 28th edition. Most of the changes involved throwing more weight to Byzantine readings in the General Epistles. Compared to N-A 27, there are different variants preferred at the following locations:  James 1:20; 2:3, 4, 15; 4:10 (now preferring μερει); 1 Peter 1:6, 16; 2:5, 25; 4:16; 5:1, 9, 10; 2 Peter 2:6, 11, 15, 18, 20; 3:6, 10 (preferring ουξ ευρεθησεται), 16, 18; 1 John 1:7; 3:7; 5:10, 18; 2 John 5, 12; 3 John 4; Jude 5 (preferring Ιησους), 18.

Comment: If you have a specific text in mind, I can give you more specific data. Saying "the critical text" is like saying "the printed Greek Bible." Virtually every printed Greek text is a critical edition.

Comment: Okay, can you give me an example from Nestle-Aland.

Comment: I just gave you a bunch from the NA28.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  I am glad to hear that they are now taking the MT more seriously, however you have not given me an example where they PREFER a byzantine reading.  All this tells me, as I understan it, is that they are deciding between two Alexandrian readings and giving more weight to a Byzantine reading in the process.

Comment: All the major variations within Alexandrian and Byzantine readings are included in the footnotes. The changes I mentioned were where footnoted (mostly Byzantine) readings were moved up to the main text and the other reading were demoted down to the footnotes.

Comment: @parap - If I'm not mistaken, Erasmus only had 7 manuscripts at his disposal.  The Nestle-Aland easily uses 10 times that number, as far as I understand.

Comment: Looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_text-type) you can see the number of texts that are used in the Byzantine family.  This number dwarfs the NA available texts.  But what is more important is the agreement among the texts compared to the NA which forces man to decide what God's Word says.

Comment: @parap - Let me add this.  The agreement among the texts in the Byzantine family (which is larger than the other families) is amazing.  However Erasmas did the world a huge disservice when on a bet which he lost, he included 1 John 5:7.  The Majority Text is what I support and think is correct.  This verse is excluded in the MT.

Answer (score 1):

The essential difference is that the NKJV is a revision of the KJV and so shares the same textual basis as the KJV, that is, the Received Text, whereas the ESV is a revision of the RSV and shares its same textual basis, that is, the Critical Text. The Received Text is the text which most consistently corresponds to the fulfillment of God's promise to preserve his Word for his church.  The Critical Text involves at least some setting aside of that promise, if not a downright ignoring of it. In other words, the theology behind the choice between the two texts is vastly different. This important difference is unfortunately too often overlooked.  The ESV is in no sense a continuation of the same approach to Scripture as was held by the translators of the KJV. The ESV is the result of the application of quite a different approach.  But most people are quite unaware of that fact, and certainly the publishers of the ESV make no effort to inform them of it, probably because they themselves regard it as an unimportant fact and do not wish their readers to hold any other view.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get an idea on how a Q&A site works.  The last clause of your last sentence detracts from your answer because you are both speculating and assigning ulterior motive. "...and do not wish their readers ..." Removing that opinion/speculation will improve your answer.  It has already attracted down votes, and I suspect that is part of the reason why. Also, [please read up on what makes a good, supported, answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For your answer to work here, you would need to provide some scholarly references to support your assertions about the ESV. As currently written, it sounds like this is just your personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I am no scholar but I have found the NKJV to be a more literal reading, e.g. Romans 12:16 in NKJV says, 'Be of the same mind toward one another...' and the ESV says, 'Live in harmony with one another...'. I easily understand both texts but wouldn't you agree that the NKJV is a more literal, and therefore more accurate, reading of God's Word?

Comment: Welcome! We're glad you are here, but this answer would be much stronger if you used sources to make your point – are you sure that the Greek is closer to the "same mind" language?  And if so, are you sure that this is a general pattern?  Evidence of both would strengthen this answer.  I hope you'll take a minute to review [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and better understand how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).